# Subscription Render Format as Excel

Tags: reporting-services

For SSRS 2016 in data driven subscription for file share and enter value of Excel for Render Format and it creates an .xlsx file.  If I use a value from the dataset, which is returned as "Excel" the created file is .xls instead, and about twice as big.

I could not find anything in ReportSever tables or views that showed exactly how the subscription was interpreted.

I would expect that the value "Excel" when pulled from the data driven query  would behave the same way (create .xlsx file) as selecting "Excel" as entered value.

Answer (score 2):

The EXCEL rendering option was left for backwards compatibility for XLS files. The format name for XLXS files is EXCELOPENXML.

[SSRS 2008 R2 Globals!RenderFormat.Name=EXCELOPENXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382146/ssrs-2008-r2-globalsrenderformat-name-excelopenxml)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017